How to read excel file and write into bigquery table by using pandas
I want to load my excel file which is in gcs bucket to bigquery. I am using pandas to read the file and write into bigquery.
But I am facing issues to load the data. The dag is successfully but data not yet loaded. How can I do so?
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
 with fs.open(f'gs://{GCS_BUCKET_NAME}/{EXCEL_FILE_PATH}', 'rb') as f:
 df = pd.read_excel(f, engine='openpyxl')
    client = bigquery.Client()
    table_ref = f"{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{TABLE_ID}"    df.to_gbq(destination_table=table_ref, project_id=PROJECT_ID, if_exists='replace')

The data is not proper format so I can't convert into csv.
To read excel file and to write in to bigquery I am using above code but data is not loading but dag is showing successful

Can the issue that the Excel data is not "proper format" easily solved by pandas? E.g. format the date  columns etc. If not, please create an additional Excel sheet that has a usefull table schema. This can be done by Excel formulas.
